# 'Unexpected token' on JSX for Django React Tutorial

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GieYIzvdt2U&list=PLillGF-RfqbbRA-CIUxlxkUpbq0IFkX60&index=2) and cant for the life of me figure out why webpack isn't recognizing JSX?  Would love someone to point out the silly thing that i'm missing :)

my full code here
https://github.com/dukarc/django-react-app

**Error:**

```
\django-react-app\leadmanager\frontend\src\components\App.js: Unexpected token (6:11)

  4 | class App extends Component {
  5 |   render() {
> 6 |     return <h1>React App</h1>;
    |            ^
  7 |   }
  8 | }
```

- Things I have Tried

  1. rm -rf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json && npm install
  2. refered back to the tutorial [github](https://github.com/bradtraversy/lead_manager_react_django) and double checked that i'm in sync
- Versions (will output more if requested ... this was just off top of my head):

  - node: 10.15.1
  - npm: 6.8.0

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "lead_manager_react_django",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development  ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked out your source code, it had a small typo, its `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID`.

Its line 10 in the following file

https://github.com/dukarc/django-react-app/blob/master/leadmanager/frontend/src/components/App.js

It works post that correction for me.

Comment: Thanks Johnny!

That was a small typo ... Per you being able to get it to work ... I ended up just cloning my repo in a new folder and trying again ... seems to be working now ... I still have no idea why the old stuff wasn't working.